# React Accordion Closing on state change

Tags: reactjs, accordion

I have 2 tabs which have accordions in those tabs. Whenever user switch between the tabs with accordion open in one tab, again coming back to the previous tab then the accordion is closed. How can we make the accordion to open until user close it.

I am using React Accordion installed from npm.

[Here i am in Tab 1 with accordion as opened, as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHBqO.png)

[Now i switched to tab 3, as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4VXv.png)

[Now again i switched from tab 3 to tab 2 then you can see here the accordion is closed automatically. Here I don't want to close the accordion on changing of tabs, it should close until user closes it.
This is the problem i am facing here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4ENC.png)

Comment: add code and more information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This probably has to do with the fact that the specific component inside the tab gets rerendered whenever you switch tabs, thus setting the useState value that deals with opening and closing the accortdion to its default value with all accordions closed. Solution is probably to move the state from the accordion to a parent component or a state management system.

Comment: Please look into the query again, i attached related images of the comment.

Comment: You need to implement the logic of mapping all active accordion ids to specific  tab value. and load the accordion according to tab value .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Have a specific `tabs state array` for all tabs and store the current state(true=open & false=close) of each tab.

And updating only the state of current tab and keeping the state of rest of the tabs as same.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const tabNumbers = 4; //number of tabs
  const [tabs, setTabs] = useState([...Array(tabNumbers).fill(false)]); //a state storing state of tabs
  const [currentTab, changeTab] = useState(0); //currently active tab

  function toggleIndex() {
    const updatedTabs = [...tabs];
    updatedTabs[currentTab] = !updatedTabs[currentTab]; //only toggle current tab's state
    setTabs(updatedTabs); //store updated tab's state
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "2rem" }}>
        {[...Array(tabNumbers)].map((_, index) => (
          <div
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => changeTab(index)}
          >
            Tab {index}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggleIndex}>
          This is the tab {currentTab}.<br /> This is currently{" "}
          {tabs[currentTab] ? "open" : "close"}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You mean storing all the opened accordions into each tabs sate array and when returning back apply the state to open it.

Comment: not just opened accordion, state of all the accordions, whether open or closed and only change the state of current tab's accordion present at tab's serial number/index.